How to create conditional compilation symbol in .NET to indicate build is from Docker?
My C# project can be built and hosted with and without Docker. Inside Program.cs, I need to know if the build is for Docker or not. How can I do something like this:
#if DOCKER

#endif


Do you really need to use conditional compilation? Have you considered using environment variables to detect if the program is running in the context of a container? See DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER and DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINERS environment variables.

A version of this project will run in Docker in the cloud and a version will run on-premises hosted as a Windows service. So I do need to add features specific to hosting on-premises at compile time.

You want to create new build configuration e.g. Docker-Release and add conditional compilation symbol e.g. DOCKER to that configuration.
Documentation:
Understand build configurations
Create and edit configurations
